# javascript popup window and reload

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a slight variation on the window.opener.reload javascript.

Normally, if I want to reload a page after closing a pop-up window I use

```
   window.opener.reload(true)
```

But this time i want to load a different url into the `opener` window.

So i tried this:

```
  window.opener.href('url').reload(true);
```

But this isn't working. Any ideas on why it isn't working and how I can make it work??

Thanks
jw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign to `location.href`:

```
opener.location.href = "url";
```

Comment: Perfect -- thanks -- is it fair to say if `location` is a property of `opener` - it's default value is the original url of the window -- but the value changes if specified by the method `href`???

Comment: @Jeff Yes, `location` is a special property.

Comment: Super late comment: @DigitalPlane This doesn't work in IE8 on Win7. It opens a new window instead. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

This might work (subject to same-origin policy restrictions):

`window.opener.location = url;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
window.opener.location.href = "somepage.htm";
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to reload page when set a new uri (second case) you must code directly:

```
opener.location.href = "url";
```