# Pop window not opening at code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

After open pop window, i need to reload my page. here page gets reloaded but pop window not opened. How to solve it.

```
string url = "Popup.aspx";
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
Response.Redirect("~/mysamepage.aspx", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a Reload in the javascript by appending it to the `s` string:

```
window.location.reload(false);

// If you need to fetch the webpage from the web-server again (where the page 
//contents change dynamically) pass the argument as 'true' instead of 'false'.
```

eg

```
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');window.location.reload(false);";
```

or try:

```
window.opener.href('url').reload(true);
```

Comment: its continuously loading. Not open my page

Comment: Not opening your popup-page, have you disabled popup blocker? Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599382/javascript-popup-window-and-reload